# How do I change the times Ubuntu updates?

Tags: updates, power-management

I'm new to Ubuntu, for some context (summary below) my bf and I want to sleep on discord calls and last night it was interrupted. Either by Ubuntu auto updating during the night or by me tossing and turning enough to send my plushie flying to my laptop's power button.

Question proper: How do I change the time of day Ubuntu will update? Also, can I change its behaviour (and how?) when I close the laptop's lid so it just dims the screen and doesn't go to sleep?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. In this question answer site it is best to ask one question at a time. You may want to search for each of the questions first. Ubuntu does not have a time of the day for updates. You can set it up to manually update when you are not sleeping.

Comment: Ubuntu "auto updating" is designed to not be disruptive nor to interrupt, so the technical problem to be solved seems unclear.